# Incorrect migration

Tags: support, migration

Can someone explain why this question - [Are there any C#/asp.net Security libraries available?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8713374/are-there-any-c-asp-net-security-libraries-available?noredirect=1) was migrated to [DSP](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/1056/are-there-any-c-asp-net-security-libraries-available#8713433)?

I could understand it being migrated to webmasters,  webapps, security or even programmers, but DSP? Really?

Comment: Maybe it's been unmigrated?  I see it on SO and not DSP (from following your links anyway).

Comment: It doesn't say on the question that it was migrated... And also I can't find the question on DSP

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The migration was an error; a different question was intended to be migrated. The question has since been unlocked, reopened, and the migration history cleared. The DSP copy was deleted by the DSP moderators as well.

Comment: Thanks for the info and the speedy recovery :)